# Select tab based on value dropdown

Tags: excel

I have one file where all my data sits. Let's call this one "Data-File".
I have another file where all my calculations will be done. Lets call this one "Main-File".

On the Main-File I have a dropdown list. Based on the value I want to change the tab inside my Data-File where I want to search.

Let's give an example to make it a bit more clear.

In my dropdown on my Main-File I have a list of all different football leagues.
For example:

England Premier
England Championship
England League 1
etc....

In Data-File every league has his own tab where all the data sits.

England Premier is tab E0 in the Data-File
England Championship is tab E1 in the Data-File
England League 1 is tab E2 in the Data-File

So in my main file I search in the Data-file for the relevant information. I point to ('[all-euro-data-2020-2021.xlsx]E0'!$D:$D if I want to search in column D for England Premier. See the "E0".

How do I now dynamically change the E0 to E1 value if I select for example England Championship in my dropdown list. In my Data-File the England Championship is under E1.

This is driving my banana's.

Comment: INDIRECT function.

Comment: @BigBen, that far I got. But can't to seem to get it working.